# Python - choose a row from a table according to prioritized substring on a column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been stuck with this issue for a little bit, so I thought I might ask for help.

I have a series of files, each one structured like this:

```
I:8859_VEP  upstream_gene_variant   Y74C9A.2a.1
I:8859_VEP  upstream_gene_variant   Y74C9A.2a.2
I:8859_VEP  frameshift_variant  Y74C9A.2a.2
I:8859_VEP  upstream_gene_variant   Y74C9A.2a.3
I:8859_VEP  intron_variant  Y74C9A.2a.3
I:8859_VEP  downstream_gene_variant Y74C9A.6
I:8859_VEP  upstream_gene_variant   Y74C9A.2a.4
I:8859_VEP  upstream_gene_variant   Y74C9A.2a.5
I:8859_VEP  upstream_gene_variant   Y74C9A.2b
I:8859_VEP  upstream_gene_variant   Y74C9A.6
I:8859_VEP  downstream_gene_variant Y74C9A.6
```

For each file I need to print out only one line according to a prioritization of the value of the second column, in this example I would like to print the line with "frameshift_variant"; however if there weren't any "frameshift_variant" it should print the "intronic_variant", and so on ...

I tried:

```
with open('table.csv', 'r') as f:

    for line in f:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        lin = line.split("\t")

        if lin[1] == "frameshift_variant":
            print(line)
            break
        else:
            if lin[1] == "intron_variant":
                print(line)
                break
            else:
                if lin[1] == "upstream_gene_variant":
                    print(line)
                    break
```

Thank you very much to anyone who will respond!

Comment: it's not clear what you want to print. you want to print all the lines with a specific value (i.e. `frameshit_variant`) or only the first occurence? Anyway, your code is printing all the lines, because you're checking if each line contains `frameshift_variant` or `intron_variant` or `upstream_gene_variant`, and all the lines (except the `downstream` one) respond to this condition. Try to store all the values found in column 1, find the index of a value which you're intrested in, and print the line at that index

Comment: In which basis you will decide prioritization? Please provide some more explanation and it will help us a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must browse the whole file and retain the line that has the best second field. Assuming the order is 'frameshift_variant', 'intron_variant',
          'upstream_gene_variant', 'downstream_gene_variant', you could do:

```
with open('table.csv', 'r') as f:
    order = [ 'frameshift_variant', 'intron_variant',
          'upstream_gene_variant', 'downstream_gene_variant' ]
    cur = len(order)          # start with a value that will lose
    bestline = None
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()             # clean up
        row = line.split('\t')
        index = order.index(row[1])     # find order of second field
        if index < cur:                 # if better than current
            cur = index                 # store it
            bestline = line
    print(bestline)                     # display best line at end of file
```

Nota: this assumes that the file is actually a tab delimited file...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change change

```
lin = line.split("\t")
```

for

```
lin = line.split()
```

Seems like its something related to the way the csv is structured...